# How to remove different times from the date from MYSQL

Tags: mysql, date, replace

can you help me to update the column of due_date where is something like:

```
2017-12-04T02:36:00.000Z
2017-12-04T22:56:00.000Z
2017-12-04T21:34:00.000Z
2017-12-04T06:23:00.000Z
```

to get just pure date like: 2017-12-04

I can use something like:

```
UPDATE projects set due_date = REPLACE
(due_date, 'T23:00:00.000Z', '')
```

But the problem is that, in the "due_date" column times can be different like:

```
2017-12-04T22:36:00.000Z
2017-12-04T12:22:00.000Z
2017-12-04T15:22:00.000Z
..............
```

Can I update the due_date column to remove completely this part (T15:22:00.000Z), and get just 2017-12-04?
Date column is varchar,

Comment: It is very bad practice to store Dates as char. use dat column type instead

Comment: What is the data type of `due_date` ?

Comment: @GordonLinoff *Date column is varchar,*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Execute this query
UPDATE projects set due_date = CAST(due_date AS DATE)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE projects SET due_date = DATE(due_date)
```

... done.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date

Answer (score 0):

If `due_date` is a string, I would recommend:

```
update projects
     set due_date = left(due_date, 10);
```

Then, I would recommend changing the type:

```
alter table projects alter column due_date date;
```

You should use the appropriate type for your columns.  Date/time values should not be stored as strings.

Comment: THANKS WORKS GOOD :)